# Play FakeRequest with Specs2 remembers Request across tests

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I have a small Play (2.1.2) application that tries to store some data and perform a redirect. I have 2 specs:

```
"save the user" in {
  running(FakeApplication()) {
    val Some(create) = route(
      FakeRequest(PUT, "/users")
        .withSession(("user-id", user_id))
        .withFormUrlEncodedBody(("username", any_username))
    )

    status(create) must equalTo(SEE_OTHER)
    redirectLocation(create).map(_ must equalTo("/profile")) getOrElse failure("missing redirect location")
  }
}

"display errors with missing username" in {
  running(FakeApplication()) {
    val Some(create) = route(
      FakeRequest(PUT, "/users")
        .withSession(("user-id", user_id))
    )

    status(create) must equalTo(BAD_REQUEST)
    contentAsString(create) must contain ("This field is required")
  }
}
```

When I run these tests, the second test has the same result as the first one, so a `SEE_OTHER` instead of the `BAD_REQUEST`. When I change the order of the tests, both work fine. The second one also passes when I delete the first one.

Does Scala / Play / Specs2 somehow remember state across tests or requests? Is there anything I need to do to ensure they run in isolation?

EDIT:

The code in my controller looks like this:

```
val form: Form[User] = Form(
  mapping(
    "username" -> nonEmptyText
  )(user => User(username))(user=> Some(user.username))
)

form.bindFromRequest.fold(
  errors => BadRequest(views.html.signup(errors)),
  user => Redirect("/profile")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playframework 2/Specs2 does not keep state between tests unless you keep state in your test classes, your application or any external place you keep data.

If for example your application would save a user to a database in one test and test for the existance of that user in another test then of course that would make your test interfere with each other.

So I guess you need to figure out some way to clean out the database where you keep your data between each test.

Comment: I added my controller code, it seems like the `bindFromRequest` is telling me that the form is OK while I have specified a `nonEmptyText` for the `username` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction to check my database contents again, there indeed was an insert statement missing in this test. Why deleting another test fixed it remains a mystery to me, but it works now!